# Use third party library in java using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My program needs to work with rational numbers, so I find JScience(http://jscience.org/) could be helpful. Here is what I did to import the library:
I left-clicked on my project   => Properties => Java Build Path => Add External JARs

When I ran the code, this message showed up:

Usage: java [-cp javolution.jar] -jar jscience.jar [arg]
where arg is one of:
    version (to show version information)
    test    (to perform self-tests)
    perf    (to run benchmark)

I guess I need to compile and run the code manually, how can I do it using Eclipse?

Comment: When you "ran the code", what code did you run?  How did you run it?  How are you using the library?  It seems like you tried to run the `main` from the JScience jar, which includes some helpful things like printing its version and running self-tests.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I was using the rational class in JScience, so I imported org.jscience.mathematics.number.Rational. Then I created a Rational object, and tried to print it out.

Comment: Are you running this in Eclipse?  Or trying from the command line?

Comment: I am running this in Eclipse

Comment: Did you add jscience.jar in jscience-4.3.1-bin?